# What does the sentence "He all but demolished the G.O.P. in the election that followed" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> He **all but** demolished the G.O.P. in the election that followed.

I believe that I found this in a random book I was reading; and I just took note of it in my notepad since I didn't know what it meant. I'm  only struggling with the phrase "all but ..."; I used to think it meant "except for", which no matter how much I try to, I can't make it make sense within this particular sentence.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English, so I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: idiomatic expression: to all but [action verb] something=to almost x something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All but* can mean except, but most often means *everything up to*, such as,

*I all but ran to get the phone.*

This means that I hurried while not actually running. *Almost* has not quite the same meaning as *all but* because while I almost ran (as I was walking so fast) for the phone, *almost* could also mean it stopped ringing before I started, so I almost ran for it, but did not at all.

*All but*, in this case, is a qualifier to hyperbole, reducing the tabloid-esque melodrama, and avoiding outright hyperbole. It is used in the sense that it did not literally happen, no actual demolishing happened, while retaining the metaphoric sense, that a crushing victory was had.

Comment: *Almost* also means *not literally*. If I say *I **almost** did something* that means it didn't actually happen. So, your second sentence doesn't make much sense. In fact, what it means *is* essentially the same as *almost*.

Comment: I'd disagree that *almost* means *not literally*. In my humble opinion, it is emphasising the metaphoric, non literal meaning of the phrase, not that it is not factual. In the example, *He* certainly defeated *G.O.P.*, there is no question of *almost*.

Comment: What you just said doesn't address the issue. *He all but defeated the G.O.P* means the same thing as *he almost defeated the G.O.P.* In neither case was the G.O.P. *actually* defeated, but defeat was still nearly achieved. That as opposed to your example of *he certainly defeated the G.O.P*, where the G.O.P. *was* actually defeated.

Comment: We seem to be talking at cross purposes, so sorry if I have not been clear enough. The sentence in question is factually stating that the *he* won the election. That is not in question, which is why I used certainly. *He* metaphorically *demolished* his opponents. Not literally, but it is not counter factual, either. The *all but* emphasises the metaphoric meaning and reduces the melodramatic hyperbole at the same time. It does not mean literally *almost*, but more *as good as*, making the phrase more of a simile than a metaphor... if I may criminally abuse actual grammar rules to say so.

Comment: *Almost* would leave the sentence ambiguous as to whether *he* factually defeated the *GOP* while almost *demolishing* them. I hope that is clearer now.

Comment: All right, tell me if I got this right. Saying "all but" in this case means "almost". However phrasing it as "all but demolished" here is trying to emphasize how overwhelming the defeat of G.O.P. was; so much so that you could say that it were nearly demolished as a whole?

Comment: Yes, normally it would mean *almost/nearly/as good as* depending on context. The use of the word *demolished*, emphasizes how emphatic the victory was. *All but* emphasizes that the phrase is figurative and not literal, and tones down the sensationalist word choice. Imho, of course.